# How can I replace only a part of a pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've the following string:

```
var hashString = "model,5;month,10;year,2018";

document.write(hashString);
```

The pattern is **paramName1,valueName1;paramName2,valueName2;paramName3,valueName3**, and so on adding how many pair of name/value I need.

I need to change the valueNameX of a paramNameX. Tried with Regex; I'm not very able with them. End delimiter would be ; or "empty"? The beginning?

Tried with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/s0pc7ur9/6/):

```
var hashString = "model,5;month,10;year,2018";

paramName = "month,";
paramValue = 8;
hashString = hashString.replace(/paramName.*;/g, paramValue);

document.write(hashString);
```

but without any success.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without using `regex`.

Steps:

- [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your string from `;` you'll get an array.
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through every string of the array and check if it `includes` **`paramName`**. If it does return `paramName + paramValue` else return the same string.
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) back the string array while keeping `;` as separator, you'll get your expected output.

```js
var hashString = "model,5;month,10;year,2018";

var paramValueReplacer = (paramName, paramValue, str) => str.split(";")
                       .map(s => s.includes(paramName) ? paramValue ? (paramName + paramValue) : "" : s)
                       .filter(s => !!s)
                       .join(";")

var paramName1 = "month,";
var paramValue1 = 8;

console.log(paramValueReplacer(paramName1, paramValue1, hashString))

var paramName2 = "month,";
var paramValue2 = "";

console.log(paramValueReplacer(paramName2, paramValue2, hashString))
```

Comment: Its same a great approch! What if I pass an empty `paramValue` and I need to remove the corresponding `paramName`? So if I pass `paramValue  = ""` it removes `month,10` from the pattern?

Comment: I've also added this for remove `;` in the middle or start/end: `.replace(/^\;+|\;+$/g, '').replace(';;', ';');` What do you think?

Comment: @markzzz you won't need `replace(';;', ';')` if you try above given approach

Answer (score 0):

To answer exactly your question, to pass parameters into a regex you should use `new RegExp()` then, you pass the instance created to `replace()`. In other words, [RegExp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) accepts strings as parameter (or other regexp), [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts RegExp instances as parameter.

```js
var hashString = "model,5;month,10;year,2018";


var param = "month,";
var regex = new RegExp("(" + param + ")[0-9]*", "g");
paramValue = 8;
hashString = hashString.replace(regex, "$1" + paramValue);

console.log(hashString);
```

Either way, the best approach in my opinion is to crate an object like this:

```js
var hashString = "model,5;month,10;year,2018";

var obj = {};

hashString.split(";").map(o => {
  var el = o.split(",");
  obj[el[0]] = el[1];
})

obj.month = 8
console.log(obj)
```

If you want to generalize the use:

```js
String.prototype.toObject = function(l1, l2) {

  var obj = {};

  this.split(l1).map(o => {
    var el = o.split(l2);
    obj[el[0]] = el[1];
  })

  return obj;

}

var hashString = "model,5;month,10;year,2018";
var hashString2 = "model=5-month=10-year=2018";

console.log(hashString.toObject(";", ","))

console.log(hashString2.toObject("-", "="))
```

Comment: Wrong. Result must be "model,5;month,8;year,2018";

Comment: @markzzz I know, I was trying to show the key of passing parameters  to replace, not the regex itself. But I've updated the code with a proper regex.

Comment: It can be number and whatever sting, not only 0-9. But I see your point :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use a variable inside a regex object literal `//`:

Try

```
paramValue = 8;
hashString = hashString.replace(new RegExp("("+paramName+")[^;]+",'g'), "$1"+paramValue);
```

- `[^;]` Anything except `;`
- `$1` paramName is captured with `()`